# How to store more than 4 decimal places in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, number-formatting

I want to store 6 decimal digits into an array, but when I store it into array it only stores up to 4 decimal digits instead of 6. How can I store up to 6 digits into an array?

For example, if

```
 e=0.059995;
 W(l,i)=e;
```

but W(l,i) gives me the result as 4 decimal places

```
 disp(W(l,i))
  0.0600
```

How can I store 6 decimal digits into an array, i.e when I print the array it prints 
6 decimal places?

```
   disp(W(l,i))
   0.059995
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you try first to write `format long` and see that it stores more than 4 digits?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted. I agree it's an obvious error, but for somebody unfamiliar with Matlab this could be confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matlab on default settings stores up to 15 digits. It only your display format. Have a look at the [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command.

Or just type at the Matlab command prompt:

```
format long
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know you have only 6 digits you can use

```
 sprintf('%0.6f', W(l,i))
```

instead of `disp`